# Criteria Query en Many to Many con Clave Compuesta intermedio

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, criteria-api

Tengo 3 clases en el problema:
House, HouseComodity y Comodity:

```
public class House implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private HouseId id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "house", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<HouseComodity> comodities;
    ...
}
```

```
public class HouseComodity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private HouseComoditiesId id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "house_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id") })
    @MapsId("house_id")
    private House house;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("comodity_id")
    private Comodity comodity;
    ...
}
```

```
public class Comodity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

Y necesito hacer una Criteria Query (Ya que la query es dinamica y va variando en los parametros de filtrado por eso no uso JPA) que chequee que la House tiene todas las Comodities (Comparacion por name). Por lo que tengo lo siguiente:

```
    @Override
    public Predicate addFilterToHouse(CriteriaBuilder cb,CriteriaQuery query,Root root, List<String> values) {
        SetJoin<House, Set<HouseComodity>> joinComodities = root.joinSet("comodities");
        Join<HouseComodity, Comodity> joinComodity = joinComodities.join("comodity");
        Predicate[] comodities = new Predicate[values.size()];      
        for (int i = 0; i< values.size(); i++) {
            comodities[i] = cb.equal(cb.upper(joinComodity.<String> get("name")), values.get(i).toUpperCase());
        }
        return cb.and(comodities);
    }
```

Esta es la query que genera:

```
select
    house0_.id as id1_2_,
    house0_.user_id as user_id2_2_,
    house0_.description as descript3_2_,
    house0_.name as name4_2_,
    house0_.price as price5_2_,
    house0_.zone_id as zone_id6_2_
from
    house house0_
inner join zone zone1_ on
    house0_.zone_id = zone1_.id
inner join house_comodity comodities2_ on
    house0_.id = comodities2_.house_id
    and house0_.user_id = comodities2_.user_id
inner join comodity comodity3_ on
    comodities2_.comodity_id = comodity3_.id
where
    upper(zone1_.name)=?
    and upper(comodity3_.name)=?
    and upper(comodity3_.name)=?
```

Pero el problema de esta query es que las tuplas tienen un solo valor en el campo Comodity.name y al hacer el AND con mas de un valor esta arroja False. Resultado de la query sin el where:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que creo que debo agregar una subquery (en el metodo addFilterToHouse) que busque estos valores dentro de los que tiene asignados, pero no entiendo muy bien como hacerlo, es decir no se si debo usar Comodity.class o HouseComodity.class con un join:

```
Subquery<Boolean> sq = query.subquery(Boolean.class);
sq.from(Comodity.class);
sq.in(values.stream().map(value -> value.toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue hacer la subquery y utilizar CriteriaBuilder.literal() el cual nos deja poner valores planos en la query.

```
@Override
    public Predicate addFilterToHouse(CriteriaBuilder cb, CriteriaQuery query, Root root, List<String> values) {
        Predicate[] comodities = new Predicate[values.size()];
        Subquery<String> sq = query.subquery(String.class);
        Root<HouseComodity> sqRoot = sq.from(HouseComodity.class);
        Join<HouseComodity, House> joinSqHouse = sqRoot.join("house");
        Join<HouseComodity, Comodity> subComodities = sqRoot.join("comodity");
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            In<String> inClause = cb.in(cb.literal(values.get(i)));
            /**
             * TODO: Replace subquery with a view to improve performance
             */
            comodities[i] = inClause.value(sq.select(subComodities.get("name"))
                    .where(cb.and(cb.equal(sqRoot.get("id").get("houseId"), joinSqHouse.get("id").get("id")),
                            cb.equal(sqRoot.get("id").get("userId"), joinSqHouse.get("id").get("userId")))));
        }
        return cb.and(comodities);
    }
```

Esto genera la clausula where siguiente:

```
select
    house0_.id as id1_2_,
    house0_.user_id as user_id2_2_,
    house0_.description as descript3_2_,
    house0_.name as name4_2_,
    house0_.price as price5_2_,
    house0_.zone_id as zone_id6_2_
from
    house house0_
inner join house_comodity comodities1_ on
    house0_.id = comodities1_.house_id
    and house0_.user_id = comodities1_.user_id
inner join comodity comodity2_ on
    comodities1_.comodity_id = comodity2_.id
where
    (? in (
    select
        comodity5_.name
    from
        house_comodity housecomod3_
    inner join house house4_ on
        housecomod3_.house_id = house4_.id
        and housecomod3_.user_id = house4_.user_id
    inner join comodity comodity5_ on
        housecomod3_.comodity_id = comodity5_.id
    where
        housecomod3_.house_id = house4_.id
        and housecomod3_.user_id = house4_.user_id))
```

Espero que si alguien utiliza Criteria Query le sea util.